# DisplayAlert not working in a function in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am making a get request to api and it is giving me correct results! Parameters are passed to it and they are used in get request !

If parameters I passed are correct then "Authentication is Sucessfull is printed after get call !" However if Parameters are not correctly passed Application is crashing !
Invalid Credentials Alert is not getting printed ! What I am doing wrong ?

```
 async void Call(parameters)
            {
                string Url="xxx Api Url?parameters";
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                string response = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
                if(response.Equals("200"))
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Authentication is Successful", "Ok");             
                  
                }
               
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials Added", "Ok");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Application still crashing ! Suggest me a way I can stop it to Crash !

Answer (score 2):

Since this is happening inside an async method your Display Alert must need to be called on UI thread.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async()=>{
                    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Authentication is Successful", "Ok");             
  });
```

Also, your method seems to be an async void, it is generally advised as a bad practice to have an async void unless it is a lifecycle method or an event, You should consider using Threading Tasks instead i.e. `async Task Call(parameters)`.

A Microsoft blog for best practices with async-await can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

Comment: I had to set that for invalid credentials one because sucessful one was working earlier too however mine issue not solved! Application closes when invalid credentials are added however it should be showing a popup !

Answer (score 0):

`string response = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);` is most likely raising an exception when **parameters** is incorrect.

An uncaught exception will always crash your application.

For instance,

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"); // works perfectly fine.
var response2 = await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1fdqsfdqsfdqs"); //Throws a HttpRequestException because it is not found
```

In your case,

```
await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials Added", "Ok");
```

Should be inside the block of a `try {..} catch(xx)` statement